# How to remove/delete/uninstall the app from Teams admin centre

Tags: microsoft-teams

I sideloaded the app from Microsoft Teams Amin centre. Now, I want to delete the app from the centre but there is no way to delete the only thing I can do is block it.

Is there a way to delete the app or that the behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please follow below steps to remove/delete/uninstall the app from Teams admin center:

1. Login to Teams Admin Portal (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/)
2. Navigate to **Teams apps** > **Manage apps** and select the app as shown below
   [image]
3. Then click on the marked **...**(ellipse)
   [image]
4. Then click on **Actions** > **Delete**
   [image]

Comment: Is there a way to delete the app which is not sideloaded (Published in the store).

Comment: Maybe take a look at Microsoft Entra Admin Center > Azure Active Directory > Corporate Applications.

Comment: Wow, they sure managed to hide that very well. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! So between steps 2 and 3, it's not just a matter of selecting the app as indicated on step 2 and having the checkbox beside the app name show up. You have to actually click on the app name to get to the dialog box shown in step 3 to get to the ellipses.